# Proof of Fejer's lemma (exercise from book)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Does someone know where I can find the proof of the following lemma? The exercise is from Katznelson's Introduction To Harmonic Analysis. Thanks in advance for help.

[image]

Comment: It might lead into a dead end, but the immediately more useful approach appears to me is to represent $g$ by its Fourier series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint: for $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a trigonometric polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{k=-N}^Nc_ke^{-ikx}$ such that
$\|P-f\|_1<\varepsilon.$ Then
$$\left |{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)g(nt)\,dt -{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }P(t)g(nt)\,dt\right |\\\le \|g\|_\infty{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} |f(t)-P(t)|\,dt<\|g\|_\infty\,\varepsilon$$
Moreover
$$|\hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0)-\hat{P}(0)\hat{g}(0)|=|\hat{f}(0)-\hat{P}(0)|\,|\hat{g}(0)|<\|g\|_\infty\,\varepsilon$$ By the triangle inequality
we get
$$\left |{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }f(t)g(nt)\,dt -\hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0)\right |\\ \le 
\left |{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }P(t)g(nt)\,dt -\hat{P}(0)\hat{g}(0)\right |+2\|g\|_\infty\,\varepsilon$$ For $k\neq 0$ we have
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-ikt}g(nt)\,dt=\begin{cases}\hat{g}(k/n)& k/n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Thus
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-ikt}g(nt)\,dt=0,\quad n>|k| $$
For $k=0$ we get
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }g(nt)\,dt={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }g(t)\,dt=\hat{g}(0)$$ Hence
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }P(t)g(nt)\,dt=\hat{P}(0)\hat{g}(0),\quad n>N $$
Summarizing for $n>N$ we obtain
$$\left |{1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }f(t)g(nt)\,dt -\hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0)\right |\le 2\|g\|_\infty\,\varepsilon$$

Comment: Thank you very much!